# How to create editable drop down in struts 1.3

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, struts

I'm using struts drop down list in my application. But i would like make a drop down as editable one. User either can select from option or able to type it manually. I Google out but couldn't find out. Yeah, i know it not possible only struts. I just want to know how to incorporate struts with Java script.

Please sort out the issue.. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Use struts `head` tag.

Comment: Switch to Struts2 ASAP (if P)